# network activity interferes with bluetooth

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, interference

I've noticed that my Bluetooth mouse pointer slows down until it's just about unusable when I have a lot of network activity going on - for example moving a larger file from one machine to another.  My computer is a dell inspiron 1525 with bluetooth and internal wireless N.

Any idea what causes this kind of thing, or better yet what to do about it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless 802.11b/g/n and Bluetooth are both designed to use the 2.4GHz spectrum.  Wireless N also has the ability to use 5GHz, but the other side of the connection has to support it too.  More than likely, your wireless is on the 2.4GHz frequency and you're getting interference.

If this is the case, there's a few things you can try.

- (easiest) Switch to a wired mouse.  Zero interference, zero configuration.
- (easy) Turn off your wireless adapter and use an ethernet cable to connect to your router.  Zero interference, not much configuration.  It does limit your laptop's movement, however.
- (most flexible) Try configuring your router to use a different channel.  You may have to experiment to find a channel that's not picking up interference from the Bluetooth or other nearby wireless networks.
- (least flexible) Check to see if your router has 5GHz capability.  Enable it, and/or disable the 2.4GHz option.  This will get rid of the interference, but will also kill any chance of using 802.11b/g on the router.